# Calculate min and max value of a transition with index of first occurrence in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['a','b','d','d','a','b','c','b','d','a','b','a'], 
                   'sec':[3,6,2,0,4,7,10,19,40,3,1,2]})
print(df)
   ID  sec
0   a    3
1   b    6
2   d    2
3   d    0
4   a    4
5   b    7
6   c   10
7   b   19
8   d   40
9   a    3
10  b    1
11  a    2
```

I want to calculate how many times a transition has occurred. Here in the `ID` column `a->b` is considered as a transition, similarly for `b->d, d->d, d->a, b->c, c->b, b->a`. I can do this using `Counter` like:

```
Counter(zip(df['ID'].to_list(),df['ID'].to_list()[1:]))
Counter({('a', 'b'): 3,
         ('b', 'd'): 2,
         ('d', 'd'): 1,
         ('d', 'a'): 2,
         ('b', 'c'): 1,
         ('c', 'b'): 1,
         ('b', 'a'): 1})
```

I also need to get min and max of the `sec` column of those transitions. Here for example `a->b` has occurred 3 times out of them min `sec` value is `1` and max `sec` value is `7`. Also I want to get where this transition first occurred for `a->b` its 0. For the `transition_index` column I consider the first value of a transition, i.e. index of `a` and for calculating, min, max I take the second value of the transition, i.e. value at `b`.

Here is the final output I want to get:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1':['a','b','d','d','b','c','b'], 
                   'ID_2':['b','d','d','a','c','b','a'],
                   'sec_min':[1,2,0,3,10,19,2],
                   'sec_max':[7,40,0,4,10,19,2],
                   'transition_index':[0,1,2,3,5,6,10],
                   'count':[3,2,1,2,1,1,1]})
print(df)
  ID_1 ID_2  sec_min  sec_max  transition_index  count
0    a    b        1        7                 0      3
1    b    d        2       40                 1      2
2    d    d        0        0                 2      1
3    d    a        3        4                 3      2
4    b    c       10       10                 5      1
5    c    b       19       19                 6      1
6    b    a        2        2                10      1
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Also I have a huge amount of data, so I'm looking for the fastest way possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have transitions of the form `from -> to`. `'transition_index'` is based on the index of the "from" row, while the `'sec'` aggregations are based on the value associated with the "to" row.

We can shift the index and group on the ID and the shifted the ID, allowing us to use a single groupby with named aggregations to get the desired output.

---

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['index'] = df['index'].shift().astype('Int64')

(df.groupby([df['ID'].shift(1).rename('ID_1'), df['ID'].rename('ID_2')], sort=False)
   .agg(sec_min=('sec', 'min'),
        sec_max=('sec', 'max'),
        transition_index=('index', 'first'),
        count=('sec', 'size'))
   .reset_index()
)
```

---

```
  ID_1 ID_2  sec_min  sec_max  transition_index  count
0    a    b        1        7                 0      3
1    b    d        2       40                 1      2
2    d    d        0        0                 2      1
3    d    a        3        4                 3      2
4    b    c       10       10                 5      1
5    c    b       19       19                 6      1
6    b    a        2        2                10      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from adding columns with previous values of *ID* and *sec*:

```
df['prevID']  = df.ID.shift(fill_value='')
df['prevSec'] = df.sec.shift(fill_value=0)
```

Then define the following function:

```
def find(df, IDfrom, IDto):
    rows = df.query('prevID == @IDfrom and ID == @IDto')
    tbl = rows.loc[:, ['prevSec', 'sec']].values
    n = rows.index.size
    return (n, tbl.min(), tbl.max()) if n > 0 else (n, 0, 0)
```

Now if you run this function e.g. to find transitions from *a*
to *b*:

```
find(df, 'a', 'b')
```

you will get:

```
(3, 1, 7)
```

Then call this function for all other *from* and *to* values.

Note that this function returns proper result even if there is no
transition between the given values. Of course, you may choose other
"surrogate" values for *min* and *max* if no transition has been found.